# Cygwin Access Windows UNC Mapped Drive

Tags: linux, cygwin, unc

I often need to do some text processing for windows network drive. Since there are so many of them I have almost all my drive letters are used (I think T is still available).

I something need to do:

cd "\lonshr-cad\cad\Feeds\BondPricesNYClose\" or
less "\lonshr-cad\cad\Feeds\BondPricesNYClose\BondPrices_display_16112011.txt"

but my Cygwin shows that the MS-DOS sytle path detected.

Is there a quick way to access these file?

Answer (score 3):

Try with the normal slash  "/" or with single quotes instead of double quotes. If you want to use an absolute path then use /cygdrive/t for the T drive

Answer (score 3):

Just use forward slashes:

```
cd //lonshr-cad/cad/Feeds/BondPricesNYClose
```

and

```
less //lonshr-cad/cad/Feeds/BondPricesNYClose/BondPrices_display_16112011.txt
```

You can also create aliases that can `cd` to these directories or `less` specific files. That way you don't have to type the entire UNC path (or copy/paste/change slashes).